# getting element names and values of json respsonse php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I would like to get all the elements and their values from the json response. I have the following response (snippet, it has more elements):

```
stdClass Object ( [Count] => 15244 [Warnings] => Array ( ) [Machines] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 23 [Modified] => 2019-09-18 06:38:04 [Created] => 2016-03-10 14:11:39 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 51 [Modified] => 2019-09-18 08:15:52 [Created] => 2016-06-15 09:13:16 )))
```

Now I would like to get the results something like:

```
ID: 23, Modified: 2019-09-18 06:38:04, Created: 2016-03-10 14:11:39
ID: 51, Modified: 2019-09-18 08:15:52, Created: 2016-06-15 09:13:16
```

The problem is, that I don't want to hard-code the element names like "ID", "Created" and so on, because the complete array per Machines has about 50 elements.

This is what I tried:

```
$obj = json_decode($body);

foreach ($obj->Machines as $comp) {
    $sup =key($comp);
    echo key($comp)."-".$comp->$sup."<br>";
}
```

But this only gives the output:

```
Id-23
Id-51
```

So I only get the first KEY showed. I don't know how to get to the next element like "Modified" in the loop.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: You need to use 2 foreach loops, first for $obj->Machines and secound from same object which call it irritation . and it fetch out all public property in your object which will be id,Modified,...

Comment: not sure how to code what you just wrote?

Comment: refer to this link 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct, though this is a multi-dimensional array.

You need several foreach loops to iterate to the dimension you want.

```
$response = [];

foreach($obj->Machines as $comp) {
    foreach($comp as $key => $value) {
        $response[$key] = '';
        foreach($value as $title => $display) {
            $response[$key] .= $title . ': ' . $display . ', ';
        }
        $response[$key] = rtrim($response[$key], ', ');
    }
}   

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: but like I mentioned in the question, I don't want to hard code the "ID" and "Modified" and so on, because the json code was only a snippet, each Machine has about 50 elements......

Comment: Ah, check back in 5 minutes please.

Comment: That should work, let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: @Jasper Once check my answer for dynamic implementation

Comment: @Rahul yours worked as well, but I need to be able to store the values in a database as well, therefore I like to keep it "simple" for myself and have control over the values and variables....but really thanks for the code!

Comment: Should have told us you need an array, output would be ready by then. No issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array map to echo the same,

```
foreach ($obj->Machines as $comp) {
    echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($val, $key) {
              return sprintf("%s:'%s'", $key, $val);
        }, $comp, array_keys($comp)))."<br/>";
}
```

**Solution 2:-**

```
foreach ($obj->Machines as $comp) {
    echo str_replace('=',':',http_build_query($comp,'',', '));
}
```

[http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) — Generate URL-encoded query string

Answer (score 1):

Convert your JSON data to array using `json_decode()`. Make an iteration over the array using [**array_map()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), again make another nested iteration using [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to replace the value to `key:value` pear format. Finally join the converted array to  string by the glue of comma.

**Code example:**

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
$result = array_map(function ($val) {
    array_walk($val, function (&$v, $k) { $v = "$v: $k"; });
    return implode(',', $val);
}, $response);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the trick now:

```
$obj = json_decode($body);
print_r($obj);

//echo $obj->Machines[0]->Id;
foreach ($obj->Machines as $comp) {
        echo "<BR>";
    foreach($comp as $key => $value){
        echo $key.":".$value." - ";
    }
}
```

Gives the output like:

```
Id:148 - Modified:2019-09-18 07:16:47 - Created:2016-11-08 08:21:36
Id:143 - Modified:2019-09-15 04:13:21 - Created:2016-11-04 05:34:01
```

Again, really great support again! thank you very much!!